# error: Multiple annotations found at this line:

Tags: java, android

I am implementing searchview in my app, for which I copied this options_menu.xml from a separate working project of searchview.

I get this error in  res/menu/options_menu.xml

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionViewClass' in package 
 'com.example.indianconstitution'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 
 'com.example.indianconstitution'
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"        // error in this line
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Can anyone figure out this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you copied this from a project that uses `appcompat-v7` into one that doesn't.

Either include `appcompat-v7`, following the instructions, or just replace `yourapp:x` attributes with `android:x` attributes. If you go this way, though, you should also replace the action view class with the corresponding one in the framework (i.e. `android.widget.SearchView`).